# Using solarium in Magento CE

Tags: magento, solr, php-5.3, zend-autoloader, solarium

Hi i want to use solarium third party library in magento CE 1.8 .
knowing that the solarium library do not conform the naming conventions of magento and zend
I want to know how can i integrate solarium or add it features into the autoloader?
is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just released a brand new free Magento extension based on Solarium.
I did also fix the Autoloader and Symfony dependency.
My implementation has an option to enable auto correct on search terms.

[Click here to see it in Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/22478/s/solr-search-based-on-solarium/)

[Click here to go to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium)

Comment: Just a question how did you deal with Autoloader and Symphony dependency ?

Comment: Ok, I've find that out thanks a lot @Jeroen Vermeulen BVBA.
you extended the varien_event_observer !
I really thank you.

Comment: Indeed I do. I created an own autoloader function, and by using the `controller_front_init_before` event I push this autoloader in front of the __autoload stack. I had to copy the `Solarium` and `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher` libraries to be able to make it work with Magento Connect.